# Running a Scala project in GCP

Tags: scala, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to run my Intellij Scala project in the cloud using GCP. I am currently trying to use Kubernetes but I am following [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/quickstarts/deploy-app-container-image) and am not finding any support for Scala. How would I run my project in the cloud?

Comment: How do you build your scala application? Probably there exists a Docker plugin that can package your app as a Docker image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am currently trying to use Kubernetes

You deploy docker containers to Kubernetes.

> I am following this tutorial and am not finding any support for Scala.

You can use any language in a docker container. In the link, only some example apps is shown for some popular languages.

What you have to do is to figure out how you build a docker container with your app. Then you can test to run that container with docker on your local machine. When that is working, you can deploy that container to Kubernetes on GCP.

Answer (score 1):

As [Jonas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76080302/7214091) said, you can deploy any `docker container` in `Kubernetes`. If you are using `sbt` to build your `scala project`, you can create a docker container using [sbt-native-packager](https://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/) plugin. This plugin lets you package your app in different formats such as deb package (for Debian), rpm package (for RedHat), and else. You can follow this page to [set up the plugin for creating a docker container](https://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/docker.html). Then, you can create your docker image and publish it using the task `docker:publish`, or create a `Dockerfile` using the task `docker:stage`.
Here you also have a post in medium that explains [how to package your scala app and then deploy it in GCP](https://medium.com/@konstantinbodnia/create-and-deploy-a-scala-http-server-to-google-kubernetes-engine-gke-36a25e395d48)